# How to get related video from videoID with youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

How can I get list related video via Youtube API.
Thanks

Comment: No, not yet.. I recently try with `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/vn9GT-3-I1M/related?v=2&alt=jsonc` and get the list video, when I compare this list and list on Youtube, I see some video miss in this list. So, I don't know this way right or wrong, [confuse..]

Comment: It's the right way. Remember that the official youtube site customizes recommendations using your history.

Answer (score 0):

you should follow these links

`For code, Documentation in .NET, PHP, Phython Etc follow

https://developers.google.com/youtube/code#sample_code

`For API overview using Youtube ChromeLess Player follow

https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started

`For Controls of Youtube Player (like related Videos) follow

http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

Following are some sample codes

`For PHP
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/

`For ASP.NET
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42324/YouTube-API-for-ASP-NET